# String slicing Python request weblink

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get links from a webpage using a Python script. But I am getting the error:

> if links[0:4] == '/wiki' and links != '#':TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.

Can you please help?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
my_url = ('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashmir')
response = requests.get(my_url)
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
for link in page_soup.find_all('a'):
links = link.get('href')
if links[0:4] == '/wiki' and links != '#':
    print("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki" + links)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need attribute selector with starts with operator

```
[href^='/wiki']
```

When using `select` you will get an empty list if no matches.

That is

```
links = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki' + item['href'] for item in soup.select("[href^='/wiki']")]
```